# Magento 2 - Custom Homepage block not showing

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, xml, containers

I have developed a custom homepage layout and applied to the homepage. I've tried to add a created block in Magento_theme/templates/html/homepage.html but it is not displaying. Can anyone check problem in my code?

```
   <body>
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>

      <referenceContainer name="main.content">
          <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="burgHomepage" template="Magento_Theme::html/homepage.phtml" />
      </referenceContainer>
    </body>
```

Comment: Please show FUll XML code and where you added this

Comment: You can create blocks and display them via widgets on homepage

Comment: @ManojDeswal Updated now, sorry! I added it in my custom homepage layout magento_theme/page_layout/homepage.xml

Comment: why you are using body tag in between of code?

Comment: @ManojDeswal I saw it on an answer on another question and I was just trying it, I can get my header and footer to show ok, in the middle it just says Home Page and my block doesnt show, do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: check updated code and try

Comment: @ManojDeswal now I just get a blank page?

Comment: Blank page without header/footer ? check in admin header which page is selected as homepage to dispaly

Comment: @ManojDeswal The homepage is set to display as the homepage, when I took the body tags out it displayed, but still without my block ?

Comment: is it showing header/footer if yes....than create block from admin and call those block to homepage.phtml. This will be more convenient to manage the content of block

Comment: Yes it shows the header and footer! thankyou, How do I create a homepage.phtml and set me homepage to use that?

Comment: actually you are using a more complex way to create custom homepage, this can be done via admin simply creating pages/blocks and then selecting that page as homepage .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61987/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-tom).

Comment: Check my answer to create custom homepage in simple way via admin , let me know if this help you out

Comment: @ManojDeswal I managed to fix it, when I moved homepage.phtml out of html/ it worked for some reason! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome Always happy to help ! Well you can do the same via admin as well. And managing content will be more easy to you.

Answer (score 5):

Create Your **Custom Homepage in 4 Simple steps via admin onl**y

1 ) Create a page For example **custom-homepage** Now you can **directly put your content** here and the go through with **4th step**

2 ) For easy management of sections **Create multiple blocks** and put content which you want to display at homepage ex: **home-block1** , **home-block2**

3 ) Call those block to your custom-homepage using below code

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="home-block1"}}
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="home-block2"}}
```

4 ) Now Final step to display your **custom-homepage** as main homepage

```
Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page
```

I hope this will make you work easy

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you use `Magento_Theme` then your PHTML file should be located in

`vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/homepage.phtml`

please check it , or  in your theme `app/design/YourPackage/YourTheme/` in this folder create directory `Magento_Theme/templates/` and put your `homepage.phtml` in that folder

Comment: Thank you, how would I then tell Magento to use this as my homepage?

Comment: @Tom your question is not clear to me